# What does ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} represents?

Tags: cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In my CMakeList.txt, there is ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR} but I don't know the exact values it represents. So I enter something like "echo ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}", but nothing comes out. My questions are:

1. how to find out what ${xxx} represents?  
   2. are there differences between ${} and $()?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/189634/what-does-$%7Bproject_source_dir%7D-represents?/) by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on ROS Answers with karma: 49 on 2014-08-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2014-08-11**:
`echo` is not a CMake command, and `${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}` is not an environment variable (so you can't `echo` it). If you want to print it, use `message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}")` somewhere in your `CMakeLists.txt`.

**Comment by [Winston](https://answers.ros.org/users/13181/winston/) on 2014-08-11**:
Thank you @gvdhoorn, @BennyRe  and @Wolf. The combination of your three answers is the perfect answer.

**Comment by [aissa360](https://answers.ros.org/users/34849/aissa360/) on 2018-05-01**:
@gvdhoom thank you for your answer, please once you use message("PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR: ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}") where would it be displayed/printed ?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-05-02**:
On the console, during CMake configuration phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

@Wolf gave the correct answer.

For further reading please refer to the CMake documentation of the variables: http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables

---

Originally posted by [BennyRe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3675/bennyre/) with karma: 2949 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's the src folder for your project, where your package.xml and CMakeLists.txt lies, e. g.

/home/your_username/catkin_ws/src/your_package_name

if your user is names "your_username" , your catkin workspace is named "catkin_ws" and lies directly in your home folder and your package is named "your_package_name"........

---

Originally posted by [Wolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4478/wolf/) with karma: 7555 on 2014-08-11

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abcgarden](https://answers.ros.org/users/14016/abcgarden/) on 2014-08-11**:
Thank you. I think you are right. But my question goes furthur, in a general case,(not necessarily ROS), how to find out the meaning for ${}. gvdhoorn gives one possible answer.